# select neighboring divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div id="pixel_1" class="pixelarea"></div>
<div id="pixel_2" class="pixelarea"></div>
<div id="pixel_3" class="pixelarea"></div>
```

each div is 10px wide and 10px high. The whole surface is 102 divs wide and 200 divs high.(1020 pixel wide and 2000pixel high)

This is my jquery function:

```
    var getNumericPart = function(id) {
    var num = id.replace(/[^\d]+/, '');
    return num;
};

$('body').on('click','.pixelarea',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = getNumericPart($(this).attr('id')); //get only the number from the id
    var count = parseInt($("#selectedpixelsum").text());

        if($('#pixel_' +id).hasClass('selected')){
            $('#pixel_' +id).removeClass('selected');
            count--;
            $('#selectedpixelsum').html(count);
        }else{
            $('#pixel_' +id).addClass('selected');
            count++;
            $('#selectedpixelsum').html(count);
        }

});
```

How can I make sure that only adjacent divs can be selected?
By this I mean the divs below, above and to the right and left of the selected divs.

Comment: Simplest would be wrap all rows in a row container div. Getting previous and next container is simple as is using indexing of the `.pixelarea` elements within those containers

Comment: Also no need to parse the `id` and do the `if()` you use. Can simply do `$(this).toggleClass('selected')` since `$(this)` returns same element as `$('#pixel_' +id)` without needing to search for it in the DOM repeatedly

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that, the problem is I can only select the div with 10x10 pixel on the right and left side... but not the div with 10x10 pixels below and above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you know the number of items per row (102), it is simple to use the elements index to allow or disallow selection.

Left of centre is `index - 1`
Right of centre is `index + 1`
Above centre is `index - 102`
Below centre is `index + 102`

#### Assumes that only neighbours of the *first* pixel selected may be selected:

```js
/*
* Create pixel grid
*/
const $pixelsContainer = $('.pixels');

for (let i = 0; i < (102 * 5); i++) {
    $pixelsContainer.append('<div class="pixelarea" />');
}
/* END Create pixel grid */



let selectedIndex = -1;

$('.pixelarea').on('click', function() {

  const clickedIndex = $(this).index();

  if (clickedIndex === selectedIndex) {
    /*
     * Primary selected element was clicked. Remove all selections;
     */
    $('.pixelarea.selected').removeClass('selected');
    selectedIndex = -1;
    return;
  }

  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    /*
    * This is the primary selection
    */
    selectedIndex = clickedIndex;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }

  if (clickedIndex === selectedIndex - 1 || /* Left of primary */
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex + 1 ||   /* Right of primary */
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex - 102 || /* Above primary */
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex + 102) { /* Below primary */

    /*
     * Select / Deselect this element
     */
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }

});
```

```css
.pixels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1020px;
}

.pixelarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.pixelarea:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.pixelarea.selected {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pixels"></div>
```

---

#### Assumes neighbours of the *last* pixel selected can be selected:

```js
/*
* Create pixel grid
*/
const $pixelsContainer = $('.pixels');
const columnCount = 102;
const rowCount = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < (columnCount * rowCount); i++) {
    $pixelsContainer.append('<div class="pixelarea" />');
}
/* END Create pixel grid */



let selectedIndex = -1;

$('.pixelarea').on('click', function() {

  const clickedIndex = $(this).index();

  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    /*
    * This is the first selection
    */
    selectedIndex = clickedIndex;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    
    return;
  }

  if (clickedIndex === selectedIndex - 1 ||
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex + 1 ||
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex - columnCount ||
    clickedIndex === selectedIndex + columnCount) {

    selectedIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }

});
```

```css
.pixels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1020px;
}

.pixelarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.pixelarea:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.pixelarea.selected {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pixels"></div>
```

---

#### Assumes neighbours of *any* selected pixel can be selected:

(Fixes selectable pixels from flowing on to incorrect rows)

```js
/*
* Create pixel grid
*/
const $pixelsContainer = $('.pixels');
const columnCount = 102;
const rowCount = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < (columnCount * rowCount); i++) {
    $pixelsContainer.append('<div class="pixelarea" />');
}
/* END Create pixel grid */



let selectedIndex = -1;

$('.pixelarea').on('click', function() {

  const clickedIndex = $(this).index();

  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    /*
    * This is the first selection
    */
    selectedIndex = clickedIndex;
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    markAllowed();
    
    return;
  }
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('allowed')) {
    selectedIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    
    markAllowed();
  }

});

function markAllowed() {
    const row = Math.floor(selectedIndex / columnCount) + 1;

    // Allow left if we haven't clicked the first element in the row
    if (selectedIndex - 1 > 0) {
    $('.pixelarea').eq(selectedIndex - 1).addClass('allowed');
  }
  
  /*
  * Allow right if we haven't clicked the last element in the row
  */
  if (((selectedIndex + 1) / row) < columnCount) {
    $('.pixelarea').eq(selectedIndex + 1).addClass('allowed');
  }
    
  // Allow above if we haven't clicked in the first row
  if (row > 1) {
    $('.pixelarea').eq(selectedIndex - columnCount).addClass('allowed');
  }
  
  // Allow below
  $('.pixelarea').eq(selectedIndex + columnCount).addClass('allowed');
}
```

```css
.pixels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1020px;
}

.pixelarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.pixelarea:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.pixelarea.selected {
  background: limegreen;
}

.allowed {
  background: lightGreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pixels"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help and your approach. unfortunately it doesn't work properly. if the user selects a new pixel, he should be able to select the adjacent pixels again afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/spqntd5j/9/

Comment: unfortunately it is not yet working properly. Example: The user selects 5 pixels, then he can select all adjacent pixels to these 5 pieces. The user must always be able to select all adjacent pixels to his selected pixel

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/spqntd5j/18/

Comment: i have check it... it works good, but not perfect. There is a little bug. if the user select a div at the end of the row for example the 102, he must not be able to select the 103, because the 103 would be in the next line. in the same way, if the user selects the 103, he must not be able to select the 102, because it is in the previous line. The same problem exists with the column

Comment: You would need a few checks in the `markAllowed()` function: https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/spqntd5j/44/